# "Task timed out after..." when connecting to a MongoDB database in an AWS Lambda function

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am have Node.js script where in the beginning of it I connect to my MongoDB database and get a specific collection and use that within the script. I set this script up in an AWS Lambda function with a timeout of 10 seconds. When I test the AWS Lambda  with a configured test event, I get a "Task timed out after 10.00 seconds". My script is still suppose to run after it connects and finish the rest of the script. However, it stops and I get a timeout error from AWS Lambda. If I set a timeout higher, such as 15 minutes, I get the timeout error 15 minutes after I connect to the MongoDB database within the script (I got this my looking at the CloudWatch logs for the AWS Lambda function). I experimented with different timeout timings and found that for x seconds I set the timeout, my script will give the timeout error x seconds after I connect to the MongoDB database. I followed all best practices mentioned in this [article](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/best-practices-connecting-to-aws-lambda) about connecting to MongoDB from AWS Lambda and they are are: defining the MongoDB client connection outside the handler function and setting the context property `callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop` to `false`. I am not sure how to fix this. Below is some relevant code I used in my script:

`main.ts`:

```js
import { connectToDatabase } from './mongodb'
import mongodb from 'mongodb'

export const handler = async (event: any, context: any, callback: any) => {
    context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false
    const db = await connectToDatabase().then((db: mongodb.Db) => db).catch(error => error)
    var collection: mongodb.Collection = db.collection("{collection-name}")
    // Rest of the script
}
```

`mongodb.ts`:

```js
import mongodb, { MongoClient } from "mongodb"

let uri: undefined | string = process.env.MONGODB_URI
let dbName: undefined | string = process.env.MONGODB_DB

let cachedClient: null | mongodb.MongoClient = null
let cachedDb: null | mongodb.Db = null

export async function connectToDatabase() {
  if (cachedClient && cachedDb) {
    return cachedDb
  }

  if (!uri) {
    throw new Error(
      "Please define the MONGODB_URI environment variable inside .env.local"
    )
  }

  if (!dbName) {
    throw new Error(
      "Please define the MONGODB_DB environment variable inside .env.local"
    )
  }

  const client = await MongoClient.connect(uri, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })

  const db = client.db(dbName)

  cachedClient = client
  cachedDb = db

  return db
}
```

Other info: I use serverless to push the script to AWS Lambda and also using serverless plugin "serverless-webpack" for TypeScript files.

Comment: Is your lambda in VPC?

Comment: @Marcin No, it is not in a VPC.

Comment: Call `callback` or remove it.

Comment: @hoangdv I removed callback parameter and the same thing happens. I don't know how to call the `callback` i.e. where would I call in the code and what do I have to pass to it?

Comment: @hoangdv Also my handler function is an `async` so I think I wouldn't need `callback`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that AWS Lambda functions can only run for a maximum of 15 minutes (even if the code is still running after that amount of time). If I wanted to run the script for more than 15 minutes, I guess I would have to use an AWS EC2 instance.

Source: https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/faqs/

Answer (score 0):

The best practice linked in your article says `Define the MongoDB client connection outside of your handler function`. In your case you should change `const db = ...` to `db = ...` and declare `db` outside of your handler function and change it to `let db = null` like in the example in the article, so you can reuse the connections in different Lambda invocations. For example:

```js
let db = null;

export const handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
  if (!db) {
    db = connectToDatabase();
  }

  // do something with your db

  callback();
};
```

Besides that, take @hoangdv 's advice and call the `callback` function to signal AWS Lambda that you're done with handling the event. That should do the trick.

Comment: I tried this, where I define the `db` variable directly outside the `handler` function, but I get the same timeout error. I also tried it with by calling `callback()` after I connect to the database, however, the code just stops at the callback with a `null` response.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue with trying so many different approaches, having a larger maximum memory, and having a longer latency time. but they fail to solve it.

Then I found a solution by not using the whole parameter, its' value may be changed, outside of functions. Because cache can store the param in memory. it may lead the program to read the value from cache memory.

So put `cachedClient, cachedDb` defining in function:`connectToDatabase` not out of function.